# I want to show two different triangles using opengl subwindow, but only the later one shows

Tags: opengl

I want to show two different triangles in one window using opengl subwindow. But it only show the latter one. If I adjust the order of creating subwindow, the later one will always show, the second created one will not show.

[image]

If I comment out the second one, the first will show. Please help me, thanks.

[image]

The main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void mainDisplay();
void view1TriangleDisplay();
void view2TriangleDisplay();

// TODO: reshape
int initWindow(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // TODO: glutInitContextVersion(3, 0);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    // glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    GLuint window = glutCreateWindow("simple");
    glutDisplayFunc(mainDisplay);

    GLuint view1_triangle = glutCreateSubWindow(window, 0, 0, 256, 256);
    glutDisplayFunc(view1TriangleDisplay);

    GLuint view2_triangle = glutCreateSubWindow(window, 256, 0, 256, 256);
    glutDisplayFunc(view2TriangleDisplay);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

GLuint view1_program = 0, view2_program = 0;
char *load_file(const char * path)
{
    FILE *file_handler = fopen(path, "r");
    if (file_handler == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fseek(file_handler, 0, SEEK_END) == -1){
        return NULL;
    }

    long size = ftell(file_handler);
    if (size == -1){
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fseek(file_handler, 0, SEEK_SET) == -1){
        return NULL;
    }

    char *content = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char) + 1);
    if (content == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    fread(content, 1, (size_t)size, file_handler);

    if (ferror(file_handler)){
        free(content);
        fclose(file_handler);
        return NULL;
    }

    fclose(file_handler);
    content[size] = '\0';
    // printf ("path : %s, size : %ld, content : %s\n", path, size, content);

    return content;
}

void printLog(GLuint object)
{
    char *logBuffer = NULL;
    GLint logLength;
    if (glIsShader(object)){
        glGetShaderiv(object, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
        logBuffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * logLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(object, logLength, NULL, logBuffer);
    } else if (glIsProgram(object)){
        glGetProgramiv(object, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
        logBuffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(object, logLength, NULL, logBuffer);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%s", logBuffer);
    free(logBuffer);
}

GLint get_attrib(GLuint program, const char *attribute_name)
{
    GLint attribute = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute_name);
    if (attribute == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "glGetAttribLocation attribute_name %s failed\n", attribute_name);
        return -1;
    }

    return attribute;
}

GLint view1_attribute_coord2d, view2_attribute_coord2d;

GLuint create_shader(const char *path, GLenum type)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
    char *shader_src = load_file(path);
    if (shader_src == NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    char *sources[2] = {
        (char *)"#version 130\n",
        shader_src
    };

    glShaderSource(shader, 2, (const char **)&sources, NULL);
    free(shader_src);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    GLint status = GL_FALSE;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

    if (status == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "compile shader failed\n");
        printLog(shader);
        return 0;
    }

    return shader;
}


GLuint create_program(const char *vertex_path, const char *fragment_path)
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE;
    // create program
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint shader = 0;
    if (vertex_path != NULL){
        // create vertex shader
        if ((shader = create_shader(vertex_path, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)) == -1){
            return -1;
        }
        glAttachShader(program, shader);
    }

    if (fragment_path != NULL){
        // create fragment shader
        if ((shader = create_shader(fragment_path, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)) == -1){
            return -1;
        }
        glAttachShader(program, shader);
    }

    glLinkProgram(program);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "link shader failed");
        printLog(program);
        return -1;
    }

    return program;
}

int initResources()
{
    view1_program = create_program("triangle.1.v.glsl", "triangle.1.f.glsl");
    view1_attribute_coord2d = get_attrib(view1_program, "coord2d");

    view2_program = create_program("triangle.2.v.glsl", "triangle.2.f.glsl");
    view2_attribute_coord2d = get_attrib(view2_program, "coord2d");

    return 0;
}

void freeResources()
{
    // TODO: no need to free content?
    if (view1_program != -1){
        glDeleteProgram(view1_program);
    }

    if (view2_program != -1){
        glDeleteProgram(view2_program);
    }

    // NOTE: let the os handle shader
    // if (triangle_vertex_shader != 0){
    //     glDeleteShader(triangle_vertex_shader);
    // }

    // if (triangle_fragment_shader != 0){
    //     glDeleteShader(triangle_fragment_shader);
    // }
}

void mainDisplay()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void view1TriangleDisplay()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(view1_program);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(view1_attribute_coord2d);

    // attach attribute
    GLfloat triangle_vertices[6] = {
        0.0,  0.8,
        -0.8, -0.8,
        0.8, -0.8
    };

    glVertexAttribPointer(view1_attribute_coord2d, 2, GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE, 0, triangle_vertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(view1_attribute_coord2d);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void view2TriangleDisplay()
{
    glClearColor(0, 1.0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glUseProgram(view2_program);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(view2_attribute_coord2d);

    // attach attribute
    GLfloat triangle_vertices[6] = {
        0.0,  0.8,
        -0.8, -0.8,
        0.8, -0.8
    };

    glVertexAttribPointer(view2_attribute_coord2d, 2, GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE, 0, triangle_vertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(view2_attribute_coord2d);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (initWindow(argc, argv) != 0){
        return 0;
    }

    if (initResources() == 0){
        // glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay);
        glutMainLoop();
    }

    freeResources();

    return 0;
}
```

triangle.1.v.glsl

```
attribute vec2 coord2d;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

triangle.1.f.glsl

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor[0] = 0.0;
    gl_FragColor[1] = 0.0;
    gl_FragColor[2] = 1.0;
    // gl_FragColor[3] = 0.4;
}
```

triangle.2.v.glsl

```
attribute vec2 coord2d;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

triangle.2.f.glsl

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor[0] = gl_FragCoord.x/256;
    gl_FragColor[1] = gl_FragCoord.y/256;
    gl_FragColor[2] = 0.5;

    if (mod(gl_FragCoord.y, 30.0) > 15){
        gl_FragColor[3] = 1;
    } else {
        gl_FragColor[3] = 0.4;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems to me you're missing the `glutSetWindow` calls in `view1TriangleDisplay` and `view2TriangleDisplay`. Also you should probably cause screen updates somewhere (either in the idle func or as "postRedisplay" at the end of the draw functions).

Comment: @PeterT I add glutSetWindow to two view windows, but without luck.

Comment: @louxiou you need to initialize the resources for each subwindow. According to the documentation each subwindow has its own OpenGL context, so you need to compile the shaders in each context and keep track of their IDs in each context.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks!!! I move the `initResources` to its own display and it works. ;-)

Comment: Shaders are a shareable resource if the contexts are setup for resource sharing, but I'm not sure what the procedure for getting GLUT to take advantage of that is. You can probably accomplish the same thing you're doing right now if you just use 2 different viewports in the same context. "Sub Windows" are a GLUT-specific construct, it's not a standard paradigm in OpenGL development.